# How to export and ensure availability of variables from .env file on server start/restart in Python, Flask?

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, environment-variables, apache2

How to export and ensure availability of variables from `.env` file on server start/restart in Python?

I have file `.env` with secured variables, such as passwords, credentials and confidential information. I want to make this variables available on the server start/restart.

1. How to load variables from `.env` in Python?
2. How to load/reload variables from `.env` in Python, when server is restarted, reloaded?
3. How to ensure that variables is always in operational memory?
4. Is there any other better way to do solve the same technical issue?

I am using Flask and run app on Apache2 using WSGI.

My file looks the following:

`ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE_EXAMPLE=SECRET_KEY`

Comment: Since, I was not able to find any solution for the above question. I will share my solution which I think far away from being ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to put content of the file into `envvars` into `Apache2` server.

After I did this, I get everything working. I thought there is a Python way to export environment variables in `Flask` application while running on `Apache2` but nothing worked for me.

Another solution I see but has never tried myself to add into `Apache2` config `SetEnv VAR_KEY VAR_VALUE` alike statements.